# UWP App doesn't display the main view

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am trying to accomodate with the new platform, but for some reason, after I ran the application several times, it won't display it's elements. It's just like I add another element and it won't show anything. I've tried deleting everything and starting from scratch, but it does the same thing. Instead of showing at least one element, the app remains blank, even if I change the theme to Dark. The compiler also shows no error. My main page is:

```
<Page
x:Class="WDRPCIV.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WDRPCIV"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RelativePanel>
        <Button Width="40" Height="40" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" Name="RootHamburger" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" FontSize="20" Click="EvenimentMeniu"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="YOLOSWAG" FontSize="16" Margin="50,13,0,0"/>
    </RelativePanel>
    <SplitView Name="ListaNavigare" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" Name="Iconite" SelectionChanged="SchimbareFereastra">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE71D;"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="Selectare Categorie" FontSize="14" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE16D;"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="Incepere Chestionar" FontSize="14" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" GotFocus="StackPanel_GotFocus">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE115;"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="Despre" FontSize="14" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app remains Blank since your Background is `Black` and your Font Foreground is also Black. Secondly to better make use of Splitview you need to do two things first on Hamburger click you need to open splitview panel if it was closed along with defining your Content under `Splitview.Content`.
Here's the updated XAML copy and paste and you will find the difference.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>       
        <RelativePanel>
            <Button Width="40" Height="40" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" Name="RootHamburger" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" FontSize="20" Click="EvenimentMeniu"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="YOLOSWAG"  Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Margin="50,13,0,0"/>           
        </RelativePanel>
        <SplitView Name="ListaNavigare" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" Name="Iconite" >
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE71D;"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Selectare Categorie" FontSize="14" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE16D;"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Incepere Chestionar" FontSize="14" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE115;"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Despre" FontSize="14" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <Grid Background="Green" Width="550" >
                    <TextBlock Text="Your Content"/>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
```

Also make sure on inside your click event of hamburger button you have added code to open pane.

```
private void EvenimentMeniu(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListaNavigare.IsPaneOpen = true;
        }
```